# send cookie data to server without page load

Tags: javascript, cookies, setcookie

I am storing users response to questions (multiple choice) in cookie . the server extract the data from cookie only after user has attempted 20 questions .
the problem is when user has attempted only lets say , 10 question and leaves the site . responses in cookie is not available to server .
the requirement doesn't allow me to extract cookie data from every page load . 
i was thinking of triggering a page load , before cookie expires time so that , those extra data can be sync up with server . but could'nt find any solution .

appreciate any pointers on this problem

example : there are 500 pages , all are multiple choice question . 
when user attempt first question , the answer is recorded in cookie . 
second page/ second question /next page load . the server looks at cookie ...does nothing as it has only one record .
the next question ...again user response is saved in cookie . server does nothing until it finds 20 records ( indicator of 20 records is given by a flag flush, if its yes, server extract the cookie data of all 20 records/question and update the database , it then clears cookie and wait again for 20 records before extraction .
now if user solves 10 next question which are recorded in cookie and leaves the site , those extra 10 questions are lost since the server has not extracted them until last page load .

Thanks , 
Pankaj

Comment: If you are asking, "How do I trigger a function (e.g., an AJAX request) when a user navigates away from a page?" you should research the `beforeunload` [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload). If you are asking something else, I am unclear on what it is.

Comment: I don't know know when user will decide to leave the site , so the trigger should happen just before the cookie expires .or is there any way we can send the cookie data to server after user has navigated away from site .

Comment: It sounds like you're using session cookies— but bear in mind that a user can leave your site without actually ending the session; a session usually ends when the *browser* is closed.

Comment: server is any way extracting data from cookie , when the cookie data has more than 20 records . and it then clears the cookie . the problem lies when cookie has only 10 records , and user leaves the site . those 10 records are not able to sync up with server

Comment: Please explain in your question how the "server is any way extracting data from cookie, when [it] has more than 20 records".

Comment: i have added example in main question

Comment: I don't understand the problem; it sounds like you control the server logic, so why not just flush the data to your database after every question? Or, if you want to wait until at least 10 questions have been answered, why not keep the "flush" flag set to `true` after you flush those first 20?

Comment: i don't want to update database after every question , as it will give performance hit . the reason to choose cookie was to accumulate the response of 20 questions and update the database once for every 20 questions attempted .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking, "How do I trigger an event when a session cookie expires?" I don't think you can, unless the browser exposes a special API to do so. The cookie will expire either when the browser is closed, or at a specific date/time— but your script will stop running when its particular window is closed.

If you don't want to change your server logic, or offer your users an explicit "Save" button, I suggest this:

1. Add a `beforeunload` [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) handler that sends a request to the server with the "flush" flag, indicating that the user is leaving the page and the server should store all remaining data.
2. Disable that event handler if the user is about to advance to another question page.

How you implement 2. depends on how your application currently triggers the transition between question pages.

Comment: Thanks Vidor !  your approach is very helpful .

Comment: @user34484 Glad to help.

Comment: Thanks Vidor !  your approach is very helpful .point 2 i can tackle , as the server would  be knowing the next url requested , if its question url then ignore the flash flag or else honor the flush flag .the only challange i see is when user closes the tab/browser itself .

Comment: @user34484 The `beforeunload` event will fire when the user closes the tab. However, if you send an independent request in that event, the server will not be able to infer from that alone what the next page you are requesting is.